# Get array's properties that are not index

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has some properties attached to it like this:

```
    let arVar = [[{a: 1, b:2},{c:3, d:4}, {e:5}]]
     arVar.item_id = "9";
     arVar.type_id = "1";
```

`v` is the `arVar` in my code below, the array inside the `ledgerTransactionsArray`. `v` has the properties I need so that I can add it to the new `v`.

**I do not know what or how many properties `v` can have or if it will even have any property**

I want to get the `arVar.type_id` and `arVar.item_id` separately so that I can attach it to an other array:

```
$scope.ledgerTransactionsArray = $scope.ledgerTransactionsArray.map(function(v) {
//v is the array with properties that i need to attach to new v
//v has item_id, type_id
      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        console.log(v, "typeidcheck");
        v = v.map(function(subArrayObj) {

          for (let key in subArrayObj) {
            if (
              key == "credit_amount" || key == "debit_amount" ||
              key == "credit_total" || key == "debit_total"
            ) {
              if (subArrayObj[key]) {
                subArrayObj[key] = parseFloat(subArrayObj[key]).toLocaleString(undefined, {
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2
                });

              }
            }
          }

          return subArrayObj;
        })
      }
    })
```

Comment: Instead of doing `v = v.map()`, use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). This way, you don't have to reassign the non-integer keys back to the new array returned from `map`

Comment: @adiga yeah.. you're right. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic. Just use `Object.keys`. It works even for arrays.

```
> let arVar = [[{a: 1, b:2},{c:3, d:4}, {e:5}]]
> arVar.item_id = "9";
'9'
> arVar.type_id = "1";
'1'
> Object.keys(arVar)
[ '0', 'item_id', 'type_id' ]
```

If you need to remove the numeric indexes like `'0'` a rough hack (not recommended) would be:

```
> Object.keys(arVar).filter(k => !/\d+/.test(k))
[ 'item_id', 'type_id' ]
```

or better, as Nisarg points out:

```
> Object.keys(arVar).filter(k => isNaN(k))
[ 'item_id', 'type_id' ]
```